# How to correctly get the position of the cursor in Word using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a program in VBA which writes some text to a Word document, what I want to happen is when the text gets to a certain distance from the left side of the document it prints out the remaining characters up to the next full stop and then starts a new line and a tab for every character in the string. This is an example of what should happen:

[image]

The code I have below works correctly on the first page of word but on additional pages it starts to print out randomly and the value given from `objSelection.range.Information(WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)` seems to be the cause the issue.

An example of the incorrect output printed to word:

[image]

A few things I have noticed while trying to work out this issue:

If I set a break point and step through the code one line at a time everything works fine and the correct output is printed every time.

If I have the word app set to not be visible from the start it fails every time after the first page

If I have the word app set as visible it runs correctly on every page until I click somewhere on the screen outside of the word application.

This is the code I have:

```
Sub print_to_word()
        '**** SETTING UP WORD *****
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If wordApp Is Nothing Then   'if word is not open then open it
            Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 'reset error warnings
        Dim objdoc As Document
        Set objdoc = wordApp.Documents.Add 'Create a new word document
        Dim objSelection As Selection
        Set objSelection = wordApp.Selection 'Selection used to write text
        wordApp.Visible = True

        Dim wirecodes As String
        wirecodes = "114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92"   

        For x = 1 To 5 'print 5 lots of wirecodes
            Dim pos As Integer
            objSelection.TypeText (Chr(9)) 'tab
            For i = 1 To Len(wirecodes) 'loop through each character
                pos = objSelection.range.Information(WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)

                If i <> 1 And pos > 215 Then 'if the cursor is past 215 then
                    Do While Mid(wirecodes, i - 1, 1) <> "." And i <> Len(wirecodes) + 1 'print out the remaining wirecode before starting a new line
                        objSelection.TypeText (Mid(wirecodes, i, 1))
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                    If i < Len(wirecodes) Then 'if its not the last wirecode print a newline and tab
                        objSelection.TypeText (Chr(11) + Chr(9))
                    End If
                End If
                objSelection.TypeText (Mid(wirecodes, i, 1)) 'just print the character
            Next
            objSelection.TypeText (Chr(10)) 'new line
        Next
        'close word
        objdoc.Close
        Set objdoc = Nothing
        wordApp.Quit 'close word
        Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm using Microsoft office 2010 on Windows 10 any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply input the text into the document, then use the following *wildcard* Find/Replace:

```
Find = <[0-9.\*]{1,19}[!.]@.
Replace = ^&^l
```

(which can be implemented in code) you'll get:

```
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92.
114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.
123.123*.92*.92**.92
```

Is that good enough?

It's not apparent what the tab is for, but even that can be incorporated, via:

```
Find = <[0-9.\*]{1,19}[!.]@.
Replace = ^&^l^t
```

or:

```
Find = <[0-9.\*]{1,19}[!.]@.
Replace = ^t^&^l
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wont fix my issue as when the program prints the wrong output it doesn't print the right amount of wire codes on a line just to clarify a wire code is "114" or "114*". It needs to print out a number or wirecodes up to a certain postion "215" and then finish off the last wire code before starting a new line and a tab.

Comment: Do be aware, then, what the outcome is entirely dependent on what font and point size you use, plus the sizes of the left margin and the default tab-stop size, but nothing in your code seeks to control any of that. You need to provide clarification on those issues, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Print_to_Word()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, bNew As Boolean, wirecodes As String, i As Long
wirecodes = "114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92.114.114*.98.98*.99.99*.123.123*.92*.92**.92"
bNew = False
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
'If Word is not open then open it
If wdApp Is Nothing Then
  Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  bNew = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0 'reset error warnings

With wdApp
  'Hide Word if we started it
  If bNew = True Then .Visible = False
  'Turn off ScreenUpdating anyway
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  'Create a new word document
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    With .Range
      'Parse the data
      .InsertBefore vbTab
      For i = 0 To UBound(Split(wirecodes, "."))
        .InsertAfter Split(wirecodes, ".")(i) & "."
        If .Characters.Last.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) > 215 Then
          .InsertAfter Chr(11) & vbTab
        End If
      Next
    End With
    'Print & close
    .PrintOut Copies:=5
    .Close False
  End With
  'Quit Word only if we started it
  If bNew = True Then .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what is the most simple way to get the current cursor position in Word document using Excel VBA?

Comment: Instead of resurrecting old threads on quite unrelated topics, start a question of your own. You might also explain why you think knowing either the cursor position or the selection point (two entirely different things) is necessary. Neither is used in the code above.